# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'plot'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a very simple code but at the end i found problem which I couldn't solve or find any solution.
I can't draw plot. All I get is error AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'plot'

```
import pylab as p
import numpy as np
import sympy as s
import matplotlib
from random import random

X=np.arange(0,1000)
y=np.random.randint(100,size=1000)

if len(X)==len(y):
    print "ok"
else:
    print "not ok"

 polyfit=np.polyfit(X,y,6)
 poly1d=np.poly1d(polyfit)
 print poly1d


i=1
my=[]
for i in X:
    p=poly1d(i)
    my.append(p)

 print my

 p.plot(X,my)
 p.show()
```

I look after docs but I found nothing,google also can't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've overwritten the `pylab` module accidentally later on in your code by assigning something else to `p`. You can avoid this by just importing `pylab` and using, for example, `pylab.plot`.

You've also got some indentation issues, *remember that indentation matters in Python.*

**Using `matplotlib.pyplot` is generally recommended as opposed to using `pylab`.** As such I've modified the code below to use `pyplot` over `pylab`. I've also removed some unneeded parts of the code and generally tidied it up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from random import random

X=np.arange(0,1000)
y=np.random.randint(100,size=1000)

if len(X)==len(y):
    print("ok")
else:
    print("not ok")

polyfit=np.polyfit(X,y,6)
poly1d=np.poly1d(polyfit)

my=[]
for i in X:
    p=poly1d(i)
    my.append(p)

plt.plot(X,my)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Of course!I feel so stupid now.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner (and safer) to replace his object `p` with, say `myp` rather than dealing with calling `pylab` over `p` ?

Comment: You should never import `pylab` use `pyplot` intead

Comment: Can you please change the code in your answer (it is 2 lines)?  It is best to not have answers showing worst practices around (I could just change it, but that seems rude).

Comment: pylab is too pervasive to actually deprecate, so the current plan is to just pretend it does not exist ;)

Comment: Hah, yeah pylab is a pain... I'll modify the answer to make it explicit that the problem was overwriting the `p` variable, and that my newly written code is different (using pyplot).